# NSTimer - updating userInfo

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a method calling another using an NSTimer:

```
NSNumber *value = {NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.02
                                           target: self
                                         selector: @selector(configGroup:)
                                         userInfo: value
                                          repeats: YES];
```

I would love to be able to update the userInfo but there isn't a setter for it.  Without creating another ivar for the class, is there a way to update this info in the timer?

The obvious simple way is to just add the ivar, but I have a bunch of these sort of methods and my ivar list is getting a bit ridiculous.`

Thanks
- GW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `userInfo` a mutable class, such as `NSMutableDictionary`. That will allow you to modify the dictionary content.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it is hard to suggest an alternative to an ivar. However, if the number of ivars you have in your class is getting ridiculous, this is a sign of a more general problem - your class is doing too many things!

You should structure your code so that each class has a single distinct purpose. This will significantly reduce the amount of code in each class, and the amount of ivars needed to support this code.

Comment: This is all in my delegate class.  I'm sending OSC messages to another program and have to wait for replies.  This means that a somewhat extensive function had to be split up into many parts where part 2 doesn't start until the second program has told me it got everything in part 1.  Hence the NSTimer call to another method.

Comment: Furthermore, I didn't want to post all my code because it's about 989 lines of code :)

I had it much more condensed, but then had problems with sending too many messages to the second program and data was being dropped or it would crash the second program.